# Android startActionMode cannot be resolved

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-recyclerview, contextual-action-bar

I have followed a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XR0cy3YgLo), modified it slightly and then incorporated the onLongClickListener (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jGW95imi9tw) where all of the code works without errors except I am looking to use the CAB (Contextual Action Bar) in order to select multiple items and be able to delete the selected.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyHolder> {

Context c;
ArrayList<Player> players;
ActionMode mActionMode;
```

...

```
//View Holder Initialised
    @Override
    public MyHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    //View obj
    View v= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.model,null);

    //Holder
    MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(v);
    return holder;
}

//Data is bound to views
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.nameTxt.setText(players.get(position).getName());
    holder.posTxt.setText(players.get(position).getPosition());
    holder.img.setImageResource(R.drawable.marker);

    //When view is clicked
    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View v, int pos) {
            Snackbar.make(v,players.get(pos).getName() + " 1 ", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    holder.setItemLongClickListener(new ItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View v, int pos) {
            mActionMode = startActionMode(new ActionMode.Callback() {
                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    mode.setTitle("Selected");

                    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_delete:
                            //deleteClicked();
                            mode.finish();
                            return true;
                        default:
                            //doneClicked();
                            return false;
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

So the issue that I am experiencing is that 'mActionMode = startActionMode(new ActionMode.Callback() {' does not work as 'startActionMode' cannot be resolved.

I understand that startActionMode belongs to the AppCompat but I cannot understand how else to initialise the CAB. I have looked around and cannot seem to find a definitive answer to this so would appreciate any help with resolving this.

**EDIT**

I have now managed to get the CAB (Contextual Action Bar) to be shown through the long click handler (after following this tutorial: http://www.startingandroid.com/how-to-use-sqlite-database-in-android/) but I cannot work out how to actually get reference to the given item. As currently long clicking on any item will bring up the CAB but I do not have reference to the item that was clicked.

```
@Override
public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.user_row, parent, false);
    UserViewHolder userViewHolder = new UserViewHolder(v);

    v.setClickable(true);

    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Snackbar.make(v, "CLICK", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    v.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            Snackbar.make(v, "LONG CLICK", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (mActionMode != null) {
                return false;
            }
            v.startActionMode(new ActionMode.Callback() {
                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                    //get number of selected items

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.context_favourite:
                            //SQL - Favourite Item
                            mode.finish();
                        case R.id.context_delete:
                            //SQL - Delete Item
                            mode.finish();
                    }
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                    mActionMode = null;
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    });
    return userViewHolder;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`startActionMode` is method available only if your in an Activity or you have a reference of an activity to make that call.

From your code, your actually calling it from your `MyAdapter` class which is not an `Activity`.

Comment: I have managed to get the CAB (Contextual Action Bar) to be shown upon a long click but I am confused as to how I go about getting the selection to be able to perform the favourite or delete actions? As at the moment, long clicking on any item will bring up the CAB but does not have reference to any of the items in the model - please see my updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `view.startActionMode`:

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements
        View.OnClickListener,
        View.OnLongClickListener {

    public ViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        view.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        view.startActionMode(...);
        return true;
    }
}
```